# Transferring from http to https in Glassfish 3.1.1

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, glassfish-3

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.1 and JSF 2.0:

I have the following code:

```
public String doLoginOrCC() {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

    this.flightNumber = request.getParameter("flightNumber");

    if (request.getRemoteUser() == null) {
        return "login.xhtml";
    } else {
        return "https://" + request.getLocalAddr() + ":8181" + request.getContextPath() + "/bookSeat.xhtml";
    }

}
```

If user is not logged in then go to login.xhtml.

If user is logged in then go to https://localhost:8181/APP/bookSeat.xhtml

```
    Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/flightInfo.xhtml' for action '#{bookSeatController.doLoginOrCC}' with outcome 'https://127.0.0.1:8181/PlaneTicketProgram5-war/bookSeat.xhtml'
```

Do I have to add a Navigation Rule in my faces-config.xml file.

If so how would I write the Navigation Rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the HTTP scheme by a navigation case. A navigation case does basically a forward. You need to send a HTTP redirect instead. You can use [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) for this.

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
externalContext.redirect("https://" + request.getLocalAddr() + ":8181" + request.getContextPath() + "/bookSeat.xhtml");
```

You only need to add a `throws IOException` to the bean action method.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, why aren't you logging in over HTTPS? Your problem suggests that you're logging in over HTTP which thus sends the username/password unencrypted over network. Also, grabbing the raw Servlet API from under the JSF covers should be avoided as much as possible. You can grab HTTP request parameters by [`ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterMap%28%29) or, better, by [`@ManagedProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) or [`<f:viewParam>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewParam.html). You can get the remote user by [`ExternalContext#getRemoteUser()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRemoteUser%28%29).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  --Unrelated, Thanks I was going to cover that later.

Comment: @BalusC - I'm trying to use this method to go from https to http. So Having logged in with container security, I want the welcome page to switch back to http. I call redirect (from the welcome page) and end up back on the login page. Any ideas? Thanks